# Model Relationships not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to relate my Picture Model to the User Model by `belongsTo` and `hasMany` methods.

---

Heres the code written in `Picture.php` model file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Picture extends Model{

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

}
```

---

Here's the code of my `User.php` model file:

```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

  class User extends Authenticatable
  {

  use Notifiable;

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
      'email',
      'password',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
      'password', 'remember_token',
  ];

  public function pictures()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Picture');
  }

  }
```

---

I want to show the pictures uploaded by the user itself in the `manage` view which is demonstrated in my `RouteController` file:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Picture;
  use App\User;
  use DB;

 class RouteController extends Controller
  {
  /**
   * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['welcome', 'auth.login', 'auth.register']]);
  }

  public function welcome()
  {
      $pictures = Picture::all();
      return view('welcome')->with('pictures', $pictures);
  }

  public function login()
  {
      return view('auth.login');
  }

  public function register()
  {
      return view('auth.register');
  }

  public function manage()
  {
      $user_id = auth()->user('id');
      $user = User::find($user_id);
      $pictures = Picture::all();
      return view('pictures.manage')->with('pictures', $pictures->user);
  }
  }
```

---

And in the `manage.blade.php` I have to output the pictures. For that, I written this code:

```
@foreach ($pictures as $picture)
   <div class="well">
     <h3>{{ $picture->hash }}</h3>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

---

**And after all this hustle and bustle, it gives me an error which says:** `Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I want the pictures owned by the user to output in `manage` view. If you want to see all the files in the project, visit this [GitHub commit](https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/myTaswir/tree/58daca1a12f3b6d522f38b330d5fa229caeae408).

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: Does pictures table have `user_id` field?

Comment: no...... @Tpojka

Comment: You need parent constraint field in child table to be able have those related. Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're calling `$pictures->user`. `$pictures` holds a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) (enhanced array) of all pictures from this statement: `$pictures = Picture::all();`. A collection is not an object and doesn't have properties.

Also, you're not scoping your pictures to user's only anywhere. You're calling `Picture::all()` which will return all pictures from all users.

Assuming your relationships work as intended you could get currently logged in user's picture with `$user->pictures` method. This is all you need:

```
  $pictures = auth()->user()->pictures;
  return view('pictures.manage')->with('pictures', $pictures);
```

And also remove the `->user` part from `->with('pictures', $pictures)`.

Comment: hey.. thanks for the answer. But now, it gives this error:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pictures.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from pictures` where pictures.user_id = 2 and pictures.user_id is not null)`

Answer (score 1):

I think tour problem is into `manage` method.
Try to do that

```
  public function manage()
  {
      $user = auth()->user();
      $pictures = $user->pictures;
      return view('pictures.manage')->with(['pictures' => $pictures]);
  }
```

Comment: Yes that's a nicer way of doing it than my pre-edit. I would only avoid the `User::find()` call since it will do an additional query for the user, which you already have from `auth()->user()` method.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I just write i did not test. i just edited you can call the auth user doing `$user = auth()->user()` and then `$user->pictures`

Comment: @MaruAmallo, hey.. thanks for the answer. But now, it gives this error:`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pictures.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pictures` where `pictures`.`user_id` = 2 and `pictures`.`user_id` is not null)`

Comment: where do you have this error? in this method?   Maybe the relationship is wrong defined.   Did you have a `user_id ` into a pictures table?

Comment: no, i commented and migrated:refresh and removed the user_id table now. still the error continues in `manage.blade.php`

Comment: but, you need the `user_id` field.  I don't understanding you

Comment: how can I add the user_id field? @MaruAmallo

Comment: you need to see Tpojka Answer, he explain you how to do the migration file

Answer (score 1):

In your pictures migration you need to add `user_id` foreign key to be able having relation between users and pictures as you have in your models. Something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePicturesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pictures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // $table->string('storage_url');
            // $table->string('preview_url');
            $table->string('hash');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');// or $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('pictures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            // also you can put some triggered actions ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade')
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('pictures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('pictures');
    }
}
```

Just be certain that `users.id` and `pictures.user_id` have to be same type fields.

Check various options in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).
And then, what other said in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please add relationship between user and pictures.

Make new migration for add foreign key in pictures model . Please refer below link.
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Also add foreign key column name in pictures model in fillable part.

Then after change your mange method code like...

$user = User::with(['pictures'])->where('id', Auth::id())->first();

return view('pictures.manage')->with(['pictures' => $user['pictures']);